How to select the professor that would provide a Recommendation Letter for a Scholarship application?
What is the right strategy for selecting the professors that would provide a recommendation letter for a scholarship application.
I am applying for a Government scholarship, and I need to provide a few letters of recommendation. It is customary to request recommendation letter from professors that know you best and you have worked with closely. However, my former supervisor is currently on sabbatical and obtaining a recommendation letter from him is difficult. He offered to provide one but it looked a bit low effort. Another professor, who I have not directly worked with but has been associated in our group agreed to write a recommendation letter too. He was more thorough. Asked about the scholarship program, about the research proposal, and other details about the application.
The main dilemma here is choosing between which recommendation letter to submit with the application such that it improves the chances of the application to succeed. In the application form there is even a question which says: In what capacity do you know the applicant?. The two options are:

Option one: Direct supervisor, worked together for more than 5 years. Recommendation letter looks like a ChatGPT version of a previous Recommendation Letter, but still not a bad one. Sounds more generic, than tailored to the program and my overall application. This person has an h-index 60+, and is still active.
Option two: Not a direct supervisor, we do not have any publications together, was much more interested in helping with the recommendation letter, but I don't know the content of the recommendation letter. This person also has an h-index of 60+, and is retired.

What is the strategically smart decision to make in this case? What are the evaluators looking for?

Are you only allowed one?

@AzorAhai-him- Yes, unfortunately I am only allowed to pick one of the two.
